# NodeJS / Axios: How to write a PDF to disk obtained in an HTTP multipart/form-data response?

Tags: node.js, axios, multipartform-data

I'm writing a REST API client that calls an API endpoint to obtain a PDF.

I'm using **axios** to consume the API:

```
const res = await axios({
    method: 'GET',
    url: url,
    headers: {
        'authorization': 'Bearer ' + at,
    },
    proxy: false,
    httpsAgent: httpsAgent
});
console.log(res.data);
```

The response is of type multipart/form-data, in the following way:

content-type: `multipart/form-data; boundary=95b77841-292d-4a0b-a689-787fcc0aa889`

body:

```
--95b77841-292d-4a0b-a689-787fcc0aa889
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="metadata"
Content-Type: application/json

{"documentId":"123"}
--95b77841-292d-4a0b-a689-787fcc0aa889
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="document"; filename="document.pdf"
Content-Type: application/pdf

%PDF-1.4
....
%%EOF

--95b77841-292d-4a0b-a689-787fcc0aa889--
```

How can I save the 2nd part as a valid PDF file to disk?

Comment: Please share your backend code whichs refers to the upload. There are many way to do this. Lets see what you have done already please.

Comment: There is no backend code, I'm writing an API consumer that receives a file from the server in an HTTP multipart/form-data response.

Comment: A rest api falls under the category backend.